# Detect execution from startup folder

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Can i handle this suituation

My application is already in System Start up folder

- on Application start  event i want to minimize the application to system tray[ already have the working code for doing this]
- in case if user started the application by clicking on the icon [desktop icon]
  then i don't want to show it in system tray rather show it as a normal application

I define code like this

```
  private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

How can  i detect the startup is happens as user manually opens the application or its from System Startup folder

Comment: Why not pass an argument `/silent` which you handle on startup?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Can you give some more idea about it ? /silent totally new thing to me. So how can i set /silent and handle in app.xaml.cs ? Seems to be perfect solution

Comment: You just pass in an argument on your startup call, what ever its name is.

Comment: But my question how can i detect the application is started - by user clicked icon from desktop or - the automatic startup on system ON event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @PatrickHofman says in the comments you should simply use an argument.

> But my question how can i detect the application is started - by user clicked icon from desktop or - the automatic startup on system ON event?

- The automatic startup should launch your app with a `-minimized` (or whatever) switch.
- The shortcut on your desktop should execute it without any switch

And then:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Args.Length == 1 && e.Args[0] == "-minimized")
        // todo: minimize your app
}
```

Arguments are optional space delimited strings after the executable file name (*Option 1* in the image below). You can access these strings in the `StartupEventArgs.Args` string array or in the `Main` method.

[image: Shortcut options]

Alternatively, you can set the window state if the application is launched via a shortcut (*Option 2*).

Comment: `minimized` can be implemented even with startup option (shortcut's initial window state / Run entry).

Comment: @taffer Still i am  not getting exactly how to mention the arguments ? Is it some thing i need to do while creating the shortcut from installer project? [ Sorry i am not been able to under stood this idea ] . Can some one post the msdn documentation [if any?]

Comment: @JibinMathew: I have edited the answer, see the image.

Comment: @taffer YES understood and its completly a new thing for me . Thanks a lot

Comment: @taffer How can i set the startup argument on shortcut i am creating via visual studio setup and deployment project??